# JavaScript Iterate Keys and Create Div Elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a mobile app where I want users to be able to save locations in their localStorage. I have a blank HTML page called "Saved Locations." When a user navigates to this page, I want hyperlinks to be created dynamically from whatever locations are saved in the device. I'm able to iterate through the keys and list them, but I've had trouble trying to create div elements on the fly. Here's my JavaScript:

```
myApp.onPageInit('saved_locations', function (page) {

             var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
             var parent = document.getElementById("saved");

             // iterate localStorage
             for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {

             // set iteration key name
             var key = localStorage.key(i);

             // use key name to retrieve the corresponding value
             var value = localStorage.getItem(key);

             // console.log the iteration key and value
             console.log('Key: ' + key + ', Value: ' + value);

             let node = document.createElement("div")  ;
             let text = document.createTextNode(key); //value is taken from your loop
             node.appendChild(text);

             fragment.appendChild(node);

            }

             parent.appendChild(fragment);
    });
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery or you need pure javascript?

Comment: I'm using Pure JS

Comment: check out createElement function: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: I don't see any code that tries to create elements. Did you have any? Could you update your question with it?

Comment: Everything I've tried results in a blank html page. I've updated the script with the latest attempt

Answer (score 0):

Assign and Id to the element where you want them to appear. Then

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var parent = document.getElementById("yourId");

loop goes here {

    let node = document.createElement("div")  ;           
    let text = document.createTextNode(value); //value is taken from your loop
    node.appendChild(text);

    fragment.appendChild(node);
}

parent.appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: I added this with "value" changed to key, and I can't navigate to the page. I need the div IDs to change each time, correct? I would think I would tag on the value of i as it iterates through like "div_1", "div_2", etc.

Comment: No you need id only for the main container div. In your case which is <div data-page="saved_locations" class="page navbar-through no-toolbar">. Add id tag with value and try.

Comment: Ah, OK. I changed "yourId" to saved_locations and it still won't navigate to the page. The console is still logging the key values, but only the first one.

Comment: OK, got it. I needed to assign an ID to the saved_locations.html page. It's working now. Thanks!

Comment: @BillHambone try now. And let me know. Also create a fiddle in jsfiddle.net if you need any help

Comment: @BillHambone my pleasure, also dont forget to look and understand what is written not just copy and paste.

Comment: OK. Now I need to add this under a header. There are currently three keys in the localStorage and it's only adding the last one. I probably need to use insertAfter()? Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=zJzGqjVdTh

Comment: Make sure that values are not the same. Otherwise it will be replacing if I am not mistaking

Comment: Well it's looping through, so the key should be changing each time. It's only creating a div of the third(last) key.

Comment: I edited my script to follow your latest example, and I'm still getting only the last key.

Comment: Share saved fiddle not collaborative.